# Что делает setlocale()? C/C++

Tags: c, windows, кодировка, locale

Мне нужно перевести строку из **cp1251** в **Unicode**. Для этого я использую `MutliByteToWideChar(1251, ...)`.

Странность заключается в том, что если не сделать:

```
setlocate(LC_ALL, "rus");
```

То символы с кодами **[128-255]** переводятся неверно. Да, я знаю, что **setlocale()** задает используемую локаль... Но я не понимаю, какая тут связь с функцией конвертации, которой явно указали, что входная строка находится в **cp1251**.

Comment: символы интерпретируются программой не так как надо без него, откуда он знает русские или например испанские символы там написаны.

Comment: Если ты введешь например Привет то символы "превратятся" в идентичные своему коду.

Comment: Первым параметром функция **MultiByteToWideChar()** принимает кодовую страницу. Я туда передаю **1251**.

Comment: Переводятся это печатают? используйте wprintf, и вообще то локаль в консоли надо устанавливать командами и установить шрифт TrueType , если апликация консольная. Вот [тут](https://github.com/ClnViewer/LibWchar2/blob/f48af31a4f23a605bb0a3051b37a8fdcb307ff44/test/check_wchar2_MSVC.c#L39) посмотрите как шрифт установить, и разные варианты перевода консоли в Unicode режим.

Comment: Неверно переводятся - это значит, что после перевода символа в юникод его код не соответствует нормальному.
При чем тут консоль? В моей программе ее нет, и она совершенно не относится к рассматриваемому вопросу. Для задания кодовой страницы консоли существуют функции **SetConsoleCP()** и **SetConsoleOutputCP()**

Comment: Вопрос к тем, кто минусует, в чем проблема? Вы даже вопрос не прочитали, а если и прочитали, то совершенно его не поняли, судя по комментариям.

Comment: думаю главная проблема в вопросе в том, что Вы скорее всего путаете конвертацию и отображение. А так как в вопросе не показан пример "неправильности", то очень сложно понять детали.

Answer (score 1):

`setlocale` задает текущую локаль для функций стандартной библиотеки С. Она никак не влияет на функцию `MutliByteToWideChar`. В этом легко убедиться на практике, данный код отлично работает без необходимости использовать `setlocale`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[]="Привет";
    wchar_t* wstr = new wchar_t[1024];
    MultiByteToWideChar( 1251 , 0 , str , sizeof(str), wstr , 1024 );

    HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, wstr, wcslen(wstr), NULL, NULL);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Ищите проблему в другом месте.